# When to purchase a “Redemption Period” domain

Tags: domains, purchase

I am trying to purchase a domain that was registered and is in its redemption period. I have seen that I need to wait 30 days, 40 days and 45 days and 70 days (+ or - 24 hours). Here is a screenshot below. I just want to know when I need to be hitting that refresh button all day.

[image]

Also, will I have to go through the same company it was purchased from before or will it become available on lets say GoDaddy?

Comment: Without giving at least the TLD your question lacks too much data to get relevant replies.  Also you can choose any registrar to buy the domain name, once it is deleted. Before that, only the current registrar may be able to sell it to you. So this all depends on who this is and what the domain name is currently doing. For gTLDs, this is a start (but certainly not an accurate pictures of 100% of cases as any of the shown delays are under control of the relevant registry): https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/gtld-lifecycle-2012-02-25-en

Comment: At that stage, since the TLD was not disclosed we can not say it is a duplicate of a question dealing with .COM domain names...

Comment: " I need to be hitting that refresh button all day." if it is a domain that many people have interest into do not imagine for a minute that you will be able to register it by hand on sheer luck of hitting things at correct moment. Even worse, depending on where/how you check you may even be currently giving a useful piece of information (there is some interest for this domain) to some outside party... There are companies and registrars specialized in "drop catching" to re-register domain names just after their deletion. You will never be able to compete by hand with their robots...

Comment: nutshell: if it's important - pay the price and secure it. Anything else includes various elements of risk of losing the domain. If it's in the category of "it would be nice to have" then backorder it through the same registrar (since they have the control on it) if possible, and if you can't with them, then go to a reputable backorder site. Backorders are not a guarantee you'll get it and could end in an auction. . Leaving it 'til it drops is only recommended for domains that others are highly unlikely to want.